# dpkg overwrite errors on Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian

I was installing Debian Wheezy the other day and during the installation I was prompted that a firmware `bnx2-mips-09.6.2.1a.fw` is missing and I should insert an USB stick with the package so that Debian could install it.

There was an alert with text like "Missing firmware, please insert removable media with the `.fw` file to install it". I plugged in my USB stick with that file, it was formatted beforehand. I clicked "OK", the message box disappeared for a while (like 10 seconds, the diode on the USB stick was flashing) and then appeared back up.

So I moved on without that package installed.

Then I was asked to provide IP, Mask, Gate and DNS. I did, but it just showed an error. I repeated the process several times, including starting the OS installation all over again, but nothing worked.

I moved on with the installation, was asked to choose an archive mirror, but because there was no internet connection, it couldn't access any.

Finally I managed to install the system, but there was something wrong with it, because it didn't even recognize `sudo` command.

What I did was:

- There was no  internet connection, because of that missing firmware, so I installed it from the USB stick,
- After that I established the connection manually,
- I edited `/etc/apt/sources.list` and added mirrors,
- I downloaded some packages likes `sudo`, `ssh`.

Now the problem is that I can't install anything. `apt-get/aptitude update/upgrade` doesn't work, when I try to install anything, for example `curl` I get:

[image: error]

I tried to install `curl` by `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite path-to-the-deb-file` but it doesn't work either:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of curl:
 curl depends on libcurl3 (= 7.26.0-1+wheezy13); however:
  Package libcurl3 is not installed.
```

`apt-get install libcurl3` also returns a broken pipe error.

I have no further idea how to fix my problem. Any thoughts?

FIX:

As @plugwash suggested, I added ubuntu mirrors to a Debian system. Fixing the `/etc/apt/sources.list` by adding Debian mirrors solved my problem.

Comment: First, don't use `--force-`anything, unless you really know what you're doing. Second, you wrote "Unfortunately, even thought I did plug my USB stick with the firmware, it couldn't install it." More details, please. Third, your title is misleading. Please improve it.

Comment: "Unfortunately, even thought I did plug my USB stick with the firmware, it couldn't install it." - There was an alert with text like "Missing firmware, please insert removable media with the `.fw` file to install it". I plugged in my USB stick with that file, it was formatted beforehand. 

I clicked "OK", the message box disappeared for a while (like 10 seconds, the diode on the USB stick was flashing) and then appeared back up.

Comment: Ok, edit your question to include that information. You might be able to check the installation logs to see what went wrong there, though I've not run into that situation specifically. And please post the `sources.list` that you used, as plugwash suggested. There is clearly an incompatibility in the sources you used, and if you are using non-Debian mirrors, that is likely the origin of that.

Comment: Also, avoid including screenshots if possible. Pasting text is generally better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I edited /etc/apt/sources.list and added mirrors,

What lines did you add specifically? From your apt output it looks like you have added a Ubuntu mirror and that is why things are breaking.

Given this is a new install, I would recommend starting again, and next time don't go adding Ubuntu mirrors to a Debian system.

Comment: The "ubuntu mirror" thing is probably a good call. Are you are basing this on the "ubuntu" tag? Sometimes Debian packages do include that, but it it still a good indication the package is from Ubuntu. +1 on providing `sources.list`.

Comment: Yep, I added ubuntu mirrors to the `sources.list`, hopefully changing them will help.

Comment: @faheem-mitha I've very occasionally seen packages in Debian end up with ubuntu in their version numbers but never on a core package like libc-bin.